# Converting/Mapping vertical table to horizontal

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm having trouble mapping the object from database to display in my table.
I have a table like this this in my database.

```
name    total   date
Awoc1   100   9/14/2022
Awoc1   200   9/15/2022
Awoc1   300   9/16/2022
Awoc2   100   9/14/2022
Awoc2   200   9/15/2022
Awoc2   300   9/16/2022
Awoc3   100   9/14/2022
Awoc3   200   9/15/2022
Awoc3   300   9/16/2022
```

And I fetch the data as objects like this, this is the response I get.

```
[
{ "total": "300", "date": "2022-09-14", "name": "AWOC1"},
{ "total": "200", "date": "2022-09-14", "name": "AWOC2"},
{ "total": "100", "date": "2022-09-14", "name": "AWOC3"},
{ "total": "300", "date": "2022-09-15", "name": "AWOC1"},
{ "total": "200", "date": "2022-09-15", "name": "AWOC2"},
{ "total": "100", "date": "2022-09-15", "name": "AWOC3"},
{ "total": "300", "date": "2022-09-16", "name": "AWOC1"},
{ "total": "200", "date": "2022-09-16", "name": "AWOC2"},
{ "total": "100", "date": "2022-09-16", "name": "AWOC3"},   
]
```

What I was hoping to do is display the objects like this in a table. kind of horizontal.

```
        9/14/2022   9/15/2022   9/16/2022
Awoc1   100         200         300
Awoc2   100         200         300
Awoc3   100         200         300
```

Comment: i have tried doing it from back end. by fetching data like this "2022-09-14":[ {"grand_total": "300", "iemop": "AWOC01"},{"grand_total": "200", "iemop": "AWOC02"}]
"2022-09-15":[ {"grand_total": "300", "iemop": "AWOC01"},{"grand_total": "200", "iemop": "AWOC02"}], but im having trouble how to display it on front end

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would create two variables. The first variable is a list of unique dates. The second is the data grouped by the `name` and `date` columns.

```php
$data = json_decode('[
    { "total": "300", "date": "2022-09-14", "name": "AWOC1"},
    { "total": "200", "date": "2022-09-14", "name": "AWOC2"},
    { "total": "100", "date": "2022-09-14", "name": "AWOC3"},
    { "total": "300", "date": "2022-09-15", "name": "AWOC1"},
    { "total": "200", "date": "2022-09-15", "name": "AWOC2"},
    { "total": "100", "date": "2022-09-15", "name": "AWOC3"},
    { "total": "300", "date": "2022-09-16", "name": "AWOC1"},
    { "total": "200", "date": "2022-09-16", "name": "AWOC2"},
    { "total": "100", "date": "2022-09-16", "name": "AWOC3"}
]');

$data = collect($data);

$dates = $data->pluck('date')->unique();

//        $dates Output:
//
//        array:3 [▼
//          0 => "2022-09-14"
//          3 => "2022-09-15"
//          6 => "2022-09-16"
//        ]

$transformedData = $data->groupBy('name')
    ->map(function ($item) {
        return $item->groupBy('date')->flatten()->pluck('total', 'date');
    });

//        $transformedData Output:
//
//        array:3 [▼
//          "AWOC1" => array:3 [▼
//            "2022-09-14" => "300"
//            "2022-09-15" => "300"
//            "2022-09-16" => "300"
//          ]
//          "AWOC2" => array:3 [▼
//            "2022-09-14" => "200"
//            "2022-09-15" => "200"
//            "2022-09-16" => "200"
//          ]
//          "AWOC3" => array:3 [▼
//            "2022-09-14" => "100"
//            "2022-09-15" => "100"
//            "2022-09-16" => "100"
//          ]
//        ]

return view('test', ['transformedData' => $transformedData, 'dates' => $dates]);
```

**test.blade.php:** (Think of it as a pseudo-code, you can easily convert it for Vue, React, or Angular)

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            @foreach($dates as $date)
                <th>{{ $date }}</th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach($transformedData as $name => $totals)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $name }}</td>
            @foreach($totals as $total)
                <td>{{ $total }}</td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```